# Calculating the power of a test

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

> Mick thinks that he can read people's minds. To test his hypothesis you perform an experiment. you think of a number between $1$ and $10$, and then he guesses this number. This is then repeated two more times (for a total of three numbers/guesses). If he guesses right at least twice, you accept his claim that he can read minds.
>
> Calculate the power of your test, if Mick can read minds well enough to guess the right number $0.8$ of the time.

I know that the power of your test can be calculated by P(reject null hypothesis | null hypothesis is false) but I'm just really confused on how to calculate the probability of the null hypothesis being false and what the $0.8$ actually means in the question.

would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of correct guesses in $3$ trials.  You reject the null hypothesis if $X \geq 2$.  Since Mick's probability of success in any given trial is $p = 0.8$, you can use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which states that the probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials, each of which has probability $p$ of success, is 
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways exactly $k$ successes could occur in $n$ trials, $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successful trials, and $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ is the probability of failure in the remaining $n - k$ trials.